# Is QuickTime Player needed to install iOS apps through iTunes?

Tags: ios, itunes, quicktime

I need to know whether it's possible to install iOS apps through iTunes without installing QuickTime Player.

QuickTime Player is needed by iTunes only when installing media apps, is this true?

Is it needed to install QuickTime Player as well as iTunes on a Windows machine to install an app on an iOS device?

Comment: Reformatted Q, and in what single way has this to do with **Objective-C**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no need of quick time player to install iPhone app. You only need is iTunes.

Comment: .ipa files are encrypted with fairplay DRM technology.Fairplay is built into Quick Time.So isnt it needed.itunes has the user key which encrypts the master key of the application to get installed in iphone.Can you please justify why quicktime is not needed.

Comment: where do you need to decrypt that file, you just need to transfer that file ti iPhone and you can also use .app file which is not encrypted.

Comment: IPA files are DRM protected but they are unpacked on the iOS device, while iTunes does nothing more than transferring them. iTunes doesn't care, your iOS device does.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about installing ad hoc builds, do yourself a favour and get iPhone Configuration Utility from Apple's site.